# Passing bit value from C#

Tags: c#, c++, interop, bitmask

I've a C++ interface having a public property "P" which accepts bit value like 5, 6,7 etc.
Its documentation says:"Set bit mask of group type. Bit 5 is for 'a',  Bit 6 is for 'b',etc."

Am using this interface in my C# class and the type of this property "P" shown in the metadata is "char" in VS.Net.

How do I pass the bit value of 6 and 7, to this property from my C# code?
Please note that, as mentioned above, a value of type "char" should be passed from C# to this C++ interface, as this is the type which is shown in the metadata in VS.net

Please suggest.
Code:

C++ interface definition as seen from VS.Net IDE--

```
[SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    [Guid("f274179c-6d8a-11d2-90fc-00806fa6792c")]
    [InterfaceType(1)]
    public interface IAccount
    {
        char GroupType { get; set; }
    }
```

C#:

```
IAccount objAccount= new AccountClass();
((IAccount)objAccount).GroupType = ??//I need to pass char value here
```

Thanks.

Comment: With bit value do you mean that the nth bit is set, e.g. 6 would be 00100000, or something else?

Comment: yes,I've this much info as mentioned in my question.So, I wud agree on what u saying here..ie. 6 would be 00100000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `char` type in C++ is always 8 bits, which presumably means that you'd use a `byte`to represent the same thing in C#. (This assumes that your C++ platform uses standard 8-bit bytes, since a C++ `char` is defined as being 1 byte, but a C++ "byte" isn't necessarily guaranteed to be 8 bits!)

```
byte b = 0;
b |= 1 << 5;    // set bit 5 (assuming that the bit indices are 0-based)
b |= 1 << 6;    // set bit 6 (assuming that the bit indices are 0-based)
```

I'm not sure how you'd marshal that value back to your C++ routine, if that's what you need to do.

Comment: well,eventually, I need to pass a char value from C# to the C++ interface.How do i do that please?

Comment: `b &= 1 << 6;` this would only keep the 6th bit here its is basically the same as `b = 1 << 6;`, if you want to have a bitmask you need to use or `b |= 1 << 6;`

Comment: @Damokles: Oops, that was a typo. I've edited to switch `&` for `|` now.

Comment: "It's always 8 bits, as long as it is 8 bits on that platform" is a nice oxymoron.

Comment: @etarion: Yep. For all practical purposes it's always 8 bits. It was just a curiosity note really. There are/have been C++ implementations where a "byte" isn't 8 bits.

Comment: It's more about the platform than the c++ implementation on top of it. In the embedded world, CHAR_BIT > 8 is not uncommon.

Comment: Thanks LukeH.FYI, indices r 0 based.So, using ur approach, if I need to pass bit 5 and bit 6 as byte, how do I do that in the code?

Comment: @Jimmy: I'll edit the comments to reflect that, but there should be no need for any functional change. (Bits 5 and 6 using 0-based indices are the same as bits 6 and 7 using 1-based indices.)

Comment: ok LukeH..so wud this be correct?( ( IAccount ) objAccount ).GroupType = b;-->this would mean both 5 and 6 bit are getting passed..right?

Comment: @Jimmy: Yes, I think so. Although you're the only one in a position to be able to test that!

Answer (score 4):

You can use a "Enum" type which inheres from "byte":

```
[Flags]
enum BitFlags : byte
{
    One = ( 1 << 0 ),
    Two = ( 1 << 1 ),
    Three = ( 1 << 2 ),
    Four = ( 1 << 3 ),
    Five = ( 1 << 4 ),
    Six = ( 1 << 5 ),
    Seven = ( 1 << 6 ),
    Eight = ( 1 << 7 )
}

void Main()
{
    BitFlags myValue= BitFlags.Six | BitFlags.Seven;

    Console.WriteLine( Convert.ToString( (byte) myValue, 2 ) );
}
```

Output: 1100000

You need to post more information on the native method and how you're invoking it in order to help further.

```
[SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
[Guid("f274179c-6d8a-11d2-90fc-00806fa6792c")]
[InterfaceType(1)]
public interface IAccount
{
    byte GroupType { get; set; } // char in native C++ is generally going to be 8 bits, this = C# byte
}

IAccount objAccount= new AccountClass();  

( ( IAccount ) objAccount ).GroupType = ( byte )( BitFlags.Six | BitFlags.Seven );
```

Comment: Have added that info now.Please check the question.

Comment: I tried this.Am getting a build error: Error 234 Cannot implicitly convert type BitFlags' to 'char'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)...so, shall i cast myValue to char and then pass it to the property?Thanks.

Comment: @Jimmy just cast it as a byte ( byte ) myValue; And your property needs to be a byte in C#.

Comment: sorry, but that interface is from the C++ dll...so,i cannot change the property type to byte.

Comment: @Jimmy leave it as a "char" in C++, that's what im saying. C++ char type = 8 bits, C# byte type = 8 bits. C# char type = 16 bits or same as C++ wchar_t.

Comment: u r right, but the thing is the C++ interface is actually accepting bit...because of the interop, that C++ interface in .net shows char.

Comment: and as mentioned in my question above:the C++ interface has this comment:"Set bit mask of group type. Bit 5 is for 'a', Bit 6 is for 'b',etc."

Comment: Brandon, one more point..would this work given that I need to pass 5 and 6 bit as char?-->((IAccount)objAccount).GroupType= (char)(32 + 64).Thanks.

Comment: @Jimmy a C++ char = 8 bits, 32d = 00100000b, 64d = 01000000b. So, "32 | 64" = 01100000, Or 32d + 64d = 96d = 01100000b. It's all the same. You have 8 values, each value represents 1 bit of that char (byte), you can OR the bits, or add the decimal representations it'll have the same effect. Does that make sense ?

Comment: ok.thanks.But, in VS.net Immediate window,(char)(BitFlags.Five | BitFlags.Six) shows as -->48'0' and  (char)(32 + 64) shows as-->   96'`'.....so, does it mean both have different values?

Comment: @Jimmy BitFive = 16 = 2^5, BitSix = 32 = 2^6, BitSeven = 64 = 2^7. 16 + 32 != 32 + 64.

Comment: Brendon, both ur soln and LukeH's worked for me.Upvoting LukeH's one for brevity.

Comment: @Jimmy as long as you got it fixed, that's all that really matters.